# Limits with square root without complex numbers in Maxima?

Tags: complex-numbers, maxima

Currently in WxMaxima, if I do the following

```
sqrt(-5);
```

I get this as the result:

```
sqrt(5)*%i
```

Basically an imaginary number. But this is not what I want, I want to get a "Does not exist" instead. I don't want the sqrt function to return imaginary numbers.

I looked into the documentation:
https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_singlepage.html#Functions-for-Complex-Numbers

I tried setting tr_float_can_branch_complex to false like so:

```
tr_float_can_branch_complex: false;
```

But even after executing this code, sqrt still returns imaginary numbers.

---

Basically why I want to solve this is that because the following equations all return 0:

```
limit(sqrt(x * (5 - x)), x, 5);
limit(sqrt(x * (5 - x)), x, 5, plus);
limit(sqrt(x * (5 - x)), x, 5, minus);
```

But only this one should return 0

```
limit(sqrt(x * (5 - x)), x, 5, minus);
```

I want others to return "Does not exist" or it's equivalent. Got any ideas?

---

I tried the following:

```
rsqrt(x) := (
    if x < 0 then
        error("Does not exist"),
    sqrt(x)
);
```

and if I do the following I get an error (which is good)

```
rsqrt(-6);
Does not exist

#0: rsqrt(x=-5)

 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
```

but executing the following:

```
limit(rsqrt(x * (5 - x)), x, 5)
limit(rsqrt(x * (5 - x)), x, 5, plus)
```

still returns 0. It seems that rsqrt is not executed with a negative number.

---

I am currently following a course on Calculus, and am using WxMaxima to test formulas and such. I want Wxmaxima to produce the same results as the ones shown on my course. According to the course I'm following the following should produce "Does Not Exist" because you will need to take a square root of a negative number(because x apporaches 0 from the negative side), and square root of negative numbers are not allowed:

```
limit(sqrt(x * (5 - x)), x, 5);
limit(sqrt(x * (5 - x)), x, 5, plus);
```

But in WxMaxima, the above results in 0. I can't even tell that imaginary numbers were used to come to this result. It's not wrong per se, but I want my algebra system to follow the same rules as in the course I'm doing and currently there are situations where I can't even tell if and when imaginary numbers are being used.

I can follow what is happening here but maybe later in the course I'll get confused because WxMaxima uses imaginary numbers and I won't even be able to tell if it does so. I would like to avoid this if possible.

Comment: On the face of it, it seems like you can call another function afterwards to classify the result as OK or undefined or whatever. Is there reason to believe that won't work here? Can you say more about the context in which you need to solve this problem -- where are you trying to get to, what do you want to do with the result?

Comment: @RobertDodier It's that I have to use sqrt() in conjunction with limit. Added some extra explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but what is still not clear to me is the reason that you need to have `limit` report that the limit doesn't exist. It seems you can just look at the result and say, "well, it contains the imaginary unit, so the limit isn't a real number." Do you need to do this automatically? If so what is that larger system that you are working in?

Comment: @RobertDodier It is now always the case that Limit contains an imaginary unit, as in the above example, when the limit approaches 0 from the square root of a negative number and the square root of a positive number. If imaginary numbers are allowed, I will not be able to tell the difference between the two. Added more info in the question.

Comment: OK, I think I understand what's going on now. Unfortunately there isn't a way to tell Maxima that complex arithmetic is disallowed, and that only real numbers are allowed in all calculations. At this point I think the best one can do with Maxima would be to evaluate the expression in question for values near the limit point and see if they are real or complex. I know that's not entirely satisfactory.